# SQL Alter Statement for Primary Key Column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem making the column I am adding NOT NULL using the SQL ALTER statement. I am fairly novice with SQL so any guidance would be great. I am using SQL Sever 2008 and I am receiving an error stating that the column cannot be added to the table because it does not allow nulls and does not specify a default definition. I already have data in the table and I am just looking to add an incremental primary key.

This is the SQL I am using to generate the column

```
ALTER TABLE EPUpdates.GenInfo_OpType3
ADD KeyOpType Integer NOT NULL
```

This is the SQL I am using to make it a Primary Key/ Identity Column

```
ALTER TABLE EPUpdates.GenInfo_OpType3
ADD PRIMARY KEY(KeyOpType)
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what your problem is (do you get an error message). You say you've added NOT NULL to the alter table statement - but this clause does not appear in either of the alter table statements you've shown.

Comment: Updated the post to be a little more specific

Comment: Using SQL server 2008? and it has tag: mysql?

Answer (score 1):

try to add a default value to your column, but if you want to make it as a primary key, the values must be different for each row, so you have to update these value after creating the new column and before create your primary index.

```
ALTER TABLE EPUpdates.GenInfo_OpType3
ADD KeyOpType Integer NOT NULL Default 0
```

Comment: `'0'` is a char, not an integer.

Comment: If it's an `Integer` column - why make the default a **string** (`'0'`) - shouldn't it be `default 0` ??

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to to add an incremental primary key then try this

```
ALTER TABLE EPUpdates.GenInfo_OpType3
ADD KeyOpType INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```